# AWS Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As a newbie to AWS concepts, I am trying to understand ASG concept.

a) Does it work per region or per Availability Zones?

b) Do I need to have an ASG for each Availability zone, or it can scale up and down the instances from different AZs on a shared region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an autoscale group work across availability zones, but not across regions.

Though it is possible to have an ASG in a single AZ, you would certainly *want* the ASG to be in multiple AZ's, otherwise you have no real fault tolerance in the case where an AZ has problems.

Comment: Thanks @E.J, Is there any standards for calculating the ideal max size of ASG? For example is it by looking at the number of current request per second?

Comment: It will be largely dependent on your application - for example, if you had an AS group of web servers that all relied on a RDS database (for example), it wouldn't make any sense to keep scaling up more web instances if the bottleneck is the database. You need to figure out the bottlenecks in your application and see what make sense.

Comment: Some good advice about configuring ASG here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/category/auto-scaling/ and here: https://wblinks.com/notes/aws-tips-i-wish-id-known-before-i-started/#auto-scaling.